# Правильно будет поставить тире или запятую и тире?

Tags: пунктуация

> Не могу, да и, откровенно говоря — не хочу сравнивать раввина со
> служителем придуманных религий.

Здесь правильно ставить тире или запятую и тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно предложить такой вариант оформления:

*Не могу — **да и, откровенно говоря, не хочу** — сравнивать раввина со служителем придуманных религий.*

Здесь использована вставная конструкция, в середине которой обособлено вводное сочетание на основе деепричастного оборота.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, уважаемая Шарон! С удовольствием читаю Ваши ответы и на другие вопросы! :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за отзыв. Честно говоря,  приятно было слышать...